# Excel pivot table with multiple total columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way in Excel to create a pivot table with multiple column totals?

Here's column names to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | **6 Month total** | Jul | Aug | Sep | Nov | Dec | **6 Month total** | **12 Month total**

The **12 Month total** column is of course the regular Grand Total.  The two 6 Month Total columns are the ones I'm looking to create.

Answer (score 3):

Add a variable to indicate the total. In this case, 6 months is half a year, so we will call this variable "half". Sample data below for columns A,B,C

[image]

Now set up a pivot table with both half and month as rows and sales as the value, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Would be great if you copied excel output to the text file and then posted here as a code. Then it should look much nicer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to setup the variables?  I'm not seeing how to set it up.  Specifically, how do I tell the one to only include the first 12 months and the other to only include the last 6?

Comment: @mpiktas: thanks for the suggestion. I hope this is clearer now.

Comment: @zbicyclist That's cool! except the question asks for the Month to be in Column labels (trivial to figure out from your answer, I know....)